# Does Googlebot and other spiders always pull the latest content?

Tags: web-crawler, googlebot, http-caching

I understand using the following meta tags will prevent caching for web browsers but not for proxies:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

However, using cache headers server-side will prevent caching entirely.

My pages are simple .html files, not dynamic (e.g., not .php). If I use the above meta tags, considering proxies may still cache pages, will Googlebot and other spiders always pull the latest content of my site, or could they possibly not pull the latest content since I am not setting cache headers server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Using the meta tags, or the HTTP headers is no different as bot they are meant to convey a suggestion to the requesting agent. 
If the agent (Google bot or the proxy) is set to adhere to the protocol, then your pages wont't be cached.

However, bear in mind that there is some flexibilities around and both proxies and SE bots may react in a different manner event though you asked to not-cache the page.

You have to remember that the scope of Google is to index a page, and as long as they can crawl this can be done with or without the cache tag, though impeding the cache to be retained may lead to some complication on their side.